# Application programming model $filter operation

Tags: java, s4sdk

After implementing all steps in Deep dive 12, I've been trying to use $filter operation like a normal oData service should do.

[Deep Dive 12](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/05/deep-dive-9-use-the-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-in-the-application-programming-model-for-sap-cloud-platform/)

https://baseurl/odata/v2/CrudService/BusinessPartner?$filter=BusinessPartnerCategory eq 'abc'.

However, it doesn't work. It always returns the same entity set.
I've looked at its javadoc. There seems no methods for retrieving filters. I see there are getTopOptionValue, getSkipOptionValue, getSelectProperties and getOrderByProperties.

What are options to get values of $fitler operation?

Another thing is in deep dive 4. I see that the filter is hardcoded.

[Deep dive 4](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/21/step-4-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-calling-an-odata-service/)

```
final List<BusinessPartner> businessPartners =
                    new DefaultBusinessPartnerService()
                            .getAllBusinessPartner()
                            .select(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER,
                                    BusinessPartner.LAST_NAME,
                                    BusinessPartner.FIRST_NAME,
                                    BusinessPartner.IS_MALE,
                                    BusinessPartner.IS_FEMALE,
                                    BusinessPartner.CREATION_DATE)
                            .filter(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER_CATEGORY.eq(CATEGORY_PERSON))
                            .orderBy(BusinessPartner.LAST_NAME, Order.ASC)
                            .execute();
```

What do I need to build a dynamic filter statement that may contain multiple filters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also include the answer originally posted on the blogpost here. Just in case someone takes a look at Stackoverflow only.

Currently filtering is not available in the SAP Cloud Platform SDK but on the roadmap.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/danielfoehrKn/548865474b4af77f153f6df6cfbb0c0c) is a workaround using custom Query options to call the S/4HANA Cloud SDK  in a custom handler. Make a request like …. BusinessPartner?$top=10&$skip=1&BusinessPartner eq 1&BusinessPartnerCategory < 1

However this is very “hacky” and I cannot recommend this approach.

Best Regards,

Daniel